# How to call activity methods or whole activity in Map Fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I started my first experience in coding a few days ago. Didn't find an answer for my question, so I hope someone could help me.

In my project, I have a `MainActivity` with a `BottomNavigationView` using `Fragments`. I added a map as one of the fragments and it works fine.
But I changed and add some methods in the `MapsActivity`, things like device location and ask for permission. But when I run the app it doesn't call these methods, so I think it is because the `MapFragment` needs to get the methods of the `MapsActivity` but I don't know how to solve the problem and didn't find an answer for my question.

My MapFragment

```
public class Map_Fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_, container, false);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();

        }

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    }
}
```

My MapActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 150f;
    // vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;


    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: Map is ready");

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Map started");

        getLocationPermission();


    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation : get the Devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location");
                            Location currentlocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentlocation.getLatitude(), currentlocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to find location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: move the Camera to lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng" + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    private void initMap() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Init Map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;


            }
        });
    }

    private void getLocationPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grandResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onRequestPermissionResult: called");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grandResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grandResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grandResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult: failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult: Permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    //initialize our Map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
}
```

How I connect these two with each other that the MapFragment uses the methods of MapActivity?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problems correctly, you want to run `OnMapReadyCallback` related methods from activity instead of the fragment. If this is a case, you should fix your fragment like this:

```
public class Map_Fragment extends Fragment {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_,container, false);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment==null){
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            mapFragment=SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        }

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync((MainActivity) activity);
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is it start and everthing is fine but added some methods in MapActivity to locate and ask for permission but these methods never got called. My MapFragment uses the view of the MapActivity but dont use the Methods of it and i dont know how i could call the methods or the whole activity from the MapFragment it only show me the Map but didnt locate or ask for permisson.

Comment: Did you tried my code and it still doesn't work? Especially this part where you are setting an instance of OnMapReadyCallback:

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync((MainActivity) activity);
    }

Comment: Sure try it but when i started the App it shows the Map again but didnt locate or ask for permissions.

Comment: Looks like the Map_Fragment instance is not created within MainActivity class. How do you create Map_Fragment in your project?

Comment: Created it with FragmentManager in a BottomNavigationView.